# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@svgr/webpack' in '/vercel/path0'

Tags: next.js, vercel

I was deploying my next js website using vercel. But it stucks here. Help me out plz.

Below is my next.js.config

```
module.exports = {
    webpack(config) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
        });

        return config;
    },
};
```

Comment: Have you added `@svgr/webpack` to your `dependencies` in `package.json`? (adding to `devDependencies` won't work)

Comment: Adding it to dependencies worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a similar problem.
`Module not found: Can't resolve '@svgr/webpack' in '/home/ihtisham-khattak/Atarim/app_wpfeedback/src/components'`
With the current version of node, and npm
`node: v14.20.1`
`npm: 6.14.17`. In my case the problem is solved by deleting the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` files and run the `npm install` command in the terminal. I hope in your case this trick will be work.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to solve the problem was to remove the "-omit=dev" flag from the RUN command in the dockerfile. This is my how my dockerfile looks now:

```html
FROM node:20-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
COPY . .

RUN npm install --f 

# Build the app
RUN npm run build

# Expose the port
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the app
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```